# Windows Server 2012 uninstall .net framework 4.5

Tags: .net, frameworks, uninstallation

I tried to remove the .Net 4.5 framework, downloading the file from this link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Then I executed this file from the command prompt as follows:

```
dotNetFx45_Full_setup  /uninstall
```

A window appears, asking if I want to repair or remove the 4.5 framework from the computer: I select the option "remove". The program answers with this message:

*Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating system.  You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4.5 redistributable.*

What?????? I chose the option "remove" and you say that the framework is already installed???? Dear, I know this, it is for this reason that I asked you to uninstall it!!!!!

Thank you very much for any advice about uninstalling the .Net framework 4.5, I have also tried this solution without success: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx

Comment: The .NET Framework is now an integral part of Windows, other executables depend on it.  Which means that you can no longer remove it.

Comment: Thanks. These computers are really less smart than the people who deal with them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't remove the .NET framework from Windows Server 2012. 
I hope you are not aware that this is the part of Windows Server 2012 and if you uninstall it, it will remove from your computer and when your computer will start, you will not get your Windows GUI interface. It will show you only command prompt.

I have done the same mistake, I removed .Net framework and my windows stop working. I tried many things to re-install .net framework but failed.

I was searching for the solution then i got the complete solution at only one website. Everywhere is half of the solution mentioned.

If you also want to give it a try, just remove .net from Server 2012. You window will not work and you will have to follow step by step below instructions to get it back.

[How to Re-Install GUI after .net Uninstallation on Windows Server 2012](http://itbloggertips.com/2014/06/re-install-gui-net-uninstallation-windows-server-2012/)

Comment: Made this same mistake. :)

Comment: Made this same mistake yesterday. Gladly the article saved me